# Ruby on Rails: Entering new data into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a page that lets an admin user register a new user, by entering details into a form.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "signup" %>


<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="signup">
  <div class = "field">Username:  
  <%= f.text_field :username, :class => "username"  %></div>

</br>
  <div class = "field">Email:  
  <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "email"  %></div>

</br>
    <div class = "field">First Name:  
  <%= f.text_field :firstname, :class => "firstname"  %></div>

</br>
<div class = "field">Last Name:  
  <%= f.text_field :lastname, :class => "lastname"  %></div>

</br>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :admin %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :admin, :class => "admin" %>
  </div>

<div class = "field">
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Register New User", :class => "button" %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

here is the new and create actions from the admin_controller:

```
def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save


    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
end
      else
respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

Once the form is filled in, and I hit register new user, I get brought back to the home page, and the data does not go into the database.

EDIT: full log after clicking register new user
I can see that the data in the logs:

```
    Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-17 12:27:49 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Bhh2ELWIFW9bENXeQ3Yta+bJqD7Dx8os9zdvnN0m5sM=", "user"=>{"username"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.com", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test", "admin"=>"false"}, "commit"=>"Register New User"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-17 12:27:49 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" 
  Rendered projects/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

I am new to rails so please remember this when trying to help. Thanks in advance

Comment: db entries are made in the `create` action

Comment: your post request ends up in a befopre_filter named: :require_no_authentication. What's its content?

Comment: `before_filter :authenticate_user! #:except => [:show, :index] ` but this is in my projects controller. I can't seem to find the devise controller to check exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply not saving the user to the DB and are calling the wrong controller action.

First: The way this works in Rails is that usually `new` action renders the form to the user.
Once submitted the `create` action will be hit.

In `create` you then have to create a new user object containing the properties the user entered in the form. This happens through `User.new(params[:user])` (where `params[:user]` is the data the user entered into the form) and then call `.save` on the object to persist it in the database.

Here is how the `create` action code should ideally look like:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    else
      # validation failed
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'new' } #this will re-display the new form with model errors
        format.json { #give some error in the JSON }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my create action. It still doesn't seem to work after editing it to look like your suggestion.

Comment: Are there validation errors that get fired? Is the right action hit? Your log entry does not reveal what the URL or the action where. I would bet you either hit the wrong controller action.

Comment: No validation errors flag up. I have two controllers, a projects controller and admin controller. I will add a full log to my question

Comment: Obviously the action is never hit but Devise redirects the user to the root_url due to some authentication problem.